# Read xml attributes at multiple levels from a `Document`

Tags: java, xml, document

I've got the following code from a tutorial to print out xml attributes in a java app.  Eventually I will be assigning them as strings to variables.

```
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xyz:xyzcontent");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element is " + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                eElement.getAttribute("id");
                System.out.println("Link : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }
```

This is working fine, but I need to access a specific `<date>`.  There are multiple `<date>` attributes.  For instance:

```
<releasedate>
   <date>1300981500000</date>
</releasedate>
<createddate>
   <date>1300981385795</date>
</createddate>
```

How can I grab the `<createddated><date>` value instead of the `<releasedate><date>` value?  It seems like it simply selects the first one it finds.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an XPathExpression.

The code would look something like this:

```
XPathFactory xfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression createdDateExpression = xpath.compile("/createddate/date"); //or actual path
String createdDateStr = createdDateExpression.evaluate(doc);
```

You can use the expression on any Document once you compile it.

I like to use XPath for grabbing a select few elements out of an XML vs parsing the entire document into an object.

Comment: unfortunately this is not returning any results for createdDateStr.  I'm using the full path of /xyz:xyzcontent/createddate/date.

Comment: Read how to register namespaces in the XPath object here (it's fairly easy): http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html

Comment: That's helpful, but I've got what seems like an incredibly difficult example for my first one.  I'm going to submit another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable, SAXException, IOException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(your stream);
    NodeList n = doc.getElementsByTagName("root").item(0).getChildNodes();
    for(int i=0; i<n.getLength(); i++) {
        Node item = n.item(i);
        if(item instanceof Element) {
            String e = ((Element)item).getElementsByTagName("date").item(0).getTextContent();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(((Element) item).getTagName());
            System.out.println(e);
            //if you need to convert to date:
            System.out.println(new Date(Long.parseLong(e)));
        }
    }
}
```

You must use for to get a element. You cannot get a specife node, as "root\releasedate\date" without any libraries.
My output:

```
releasedate
1300981500000
Thu Mar 24 16:45:00 CET 2011

createddate
1300981385795
Thu Mar 24 16:43:05 CET 2011
```